# Can I enable International Roaming just to receive calls, by disabling Data Usage on Android (and avoid data usage cost)?

Tags: roaming

I have Android and I see that I can enable International Roaming (Connections >> Mobile Networks >> Data Roaming >> On/Off), and disable Data usage (Connections >> Data Saver >> On/Off).

However I´m not sure if this will be useful for what I need, which is BEING ABLE TO RECEIVE CALLS, BUT AVOIDING DATA USAGE since I will be connected to Wifi and I don't want expensive charging for data usage.

Is this the way to do it?

Comment: Note that features like VoLTE also use mobile data (usually not charged by the provider). However VoLTE may trigger other network calls that are charged so the charged data will be small but larger than zero. See https://android.stackexchange.com/q/248997/2241

Answer (score 1):

You should probably turn off Mobile Data completely.

- Open your phone's Settings app.
- Tap Network & internet and then Internet.
- Next to your carrier, tap Settings.
- Turn Mobile data on or off.